# Read each of elements in XML file when clicking on an item in popup menu

Tags: android

I have a XML file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Engine>
   <Engine1 Engine1="Engine1">
    <Cylinder Cylinder="Cylinder1" BP="0.01" P="0.02" T="0.04" ></Cylinder>
    <Cylinder Cylinder="Cylinder2" BP="0.01" P="0.02" T="0.04" ></Cylinder>
    <Cylinder Cylinder="Cylinder3" BP="0.01" P="0.02" T="0.04" ></Cylinder>
   </Engine1>
   <Engine2 Engine2="Engine2">
    <Cylinder Cylinder="Cylinder1" BP="0.01" P="0.02" T="0.04" ></Cylinder>
    <Cylinder Cylinder="Cylinder2" BP="0.01" P="0.02" T="0.04" ></Cylinder>
    <Cylinder Cylinder="Cylinder3" BP="0.01" P="0.02" T="0.04" ></Cylinder>
   </Engine2>
 </Engine>
```

I'm intending to create a popup menu presented list of Engines (i.e. Engine 1, Engine 2,etc.). When clicking on one of Engines in popup menu, it shows specifications related to the Engine as in XML file (i.e. click on Engine 1 in menu popup, specifications related to Engine 1 will be showed, corresponding to other Engines).

I have used Menus to represent popup menu. However, **I don't know how to read each of Engine in XML file when I click on "Engine" in popup menu.** I tried to use "switch-case" to do this, but it is not successful because our number of Engine and Cylinder is dynamic (not static with 3 Engines).

Can you guys help me to do this?   Thank you guys so much!